# The #include<iostream> exists, but I get an error: identifier "cout" is undefined. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, visual-studio-2012

I learn C++ and COM through the books.
In the IDE MS Visual Studio 2012 I have created new empty C++ project, and added some existing files to it. My CPP file contains `#include<iostream>` row, but in editor I got such messages:

> Error: identifier "cout" is undefined

end

> Error: identifier "endl" is undefined

Code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include"interfaces.h" // unknown.h, objbase.h, initguid.h

class CA {//: public IX, IY{
public:
    // Constructor
    CA();
    // Destructor
    ~CA();
    // IUnknown
    virtual HRESULT __stdcall QueryInterface(const IID& iid, void** ppv);
    virtual ULONG __stdcall AddRef();
    virtual ULONG __stdcall Release();
    // IX
    virtual void __stdcall Fx1();
    virtual void __stdcall Fx2();
    // IY
    virtual void __stdcall Fy1(){ cout << "Fy1" << endl; }  // errors here
    virtual void __stdcall Fy2(){ cout << "Fy2" << endl; }  // errors here also
private:
    long counter;
};
```

Why it happens?

Comment: Given this question ranks fairly high on google, I think it would be worth replacing this picture of code with an actual MCVE.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to specify the `std::` namespace:

```
std::cout << .... << std::endl;;
```

Alternatively, you can use a `using` directive:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

cout << .... << endl;
```

I should add that you should avoid these `using` directives in headers, since code including these will also have the symbols brought into the global namespace. Restrict using directives to small scopes, for example

```
#include <iostream>

inline void foo()
{
  using std::cout;
  using std::endl;
  cout << "Hello world" << endl;
}
```

Here, the `using` directive only applies to the scope of `foo()`.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about it. :) Now all is OK.

Answer (score 17):

You can add this at the beginning after `#include <iostream>`:

```
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 12):

`cout` is in std namespace, you shall use `std::cout` in your code.
And you shall not add `using namespace std;` in your header file, it's bad to mix your code with std namespace, especially don't add it in header file.

Comment: u mean "not add using namespace std; in your header file", u meant after header file, right? But why? Everybody use "#include<...> using namespace std;". Is there something woring doing so?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the std namespace you are missing. `cout` is in the std namespace. 
Add `using namespace std;`  after the #include

Answer (score 1):

If you have included **`#include iostream`** and **`using namespace std;`** it should work. If it still doesn't work, make sure to check that you haven't deleted anything in the iostream file. To get to you iostream file, just Ctrl +Click your `#include iostream` and it should take you to that file. You can paste the below original iostream file to your iostream file and it should work.

```
// Standard iostream objects -*- C++ -*-

// Copyright (C) 1997-2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
//
// This file is part of the GNU ISO C++ Library.  This library is free
// software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
// terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
// Free Software Foundation; either version 3, or (at your option)
// any later version.

// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
// GNU General Public License for more details.

// Under Section 7 of GPL version 3, you are granted additional
// permissions described in the GCC Runtime Library Exception, version
// 3.1, as published by the Free Software Foundation.

// You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License and
// a copy of the GCC Runtime Library Exception along with this program;
// see the files COPYING3 and COPYING.RUNTIME respectively.  If not, see
// <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

/** @file include/iostream
 *  This is a Standard C++ Library header.
 */

//
// ISO C++ 14882: 27.3  Standard iostream objects
//

#ifndef _GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM
#define _GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM 1

#pragma GCC system_header

#include <bits/c++config.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>

namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
{
_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_VERSION

  /**
   *  @name Standard Stream Objects
   *
   *  The &lt;iostream&gt; header declares the eight <em>standard stream
   *  objects</em>.  For other declarations, see
   *  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/io.html
   *  and the @link iosfwd I/O forward declarations @endlink
   *
   *  They are required by default to cooperate with the global C
   *  library's @c FILE streams, and to be available during program
   *  startup and termination. For more information, see the section of the
   *  manual linked to above.
  */
  //@{
  extern istream cin;       /// Linked to standard input
  extern ostream cout;      /// Linked to standard output
  extern ostream cerr;      /// Linked to standard error (unbuffered)
  extern ostream clog;      /// Linked to standard error (buffered)

#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_WCHAR_T
  extern wistream wcin;     /// Linked to standard input
  extern wostream wcout;    /// Linked to standard output
  extern wostream wcerr;    /// Linked to standard error (unbuffered)
  extern wostream wclog;    /// Linked to standard error (buffered)
#endif
  //@}

  // For construction of filebuffers for cout, cin, cerr, clog et. al.
  static ios_base::Init __ioinit;

_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_VERSION
} // namespace

#endif /* _GLIBCXX_IOSTREAM */
```

Answer (score -2):

You Check your C++ version or You must write this statement to global scope
using namespace std;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

you have to use:`using namespace std`
or else
you have to write `using std::endl` ie import only endl from std library.

Comment: True, but doesn't add anything to the existing answers.