# C++ Very Beginner Message-Help Appreciated

Tags: c++

Basics: C++ using Visual Studio Code, error message is in terminal, nothing is in "problems" or "Output" section.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 

{  

    int number;
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Your age is: " << number;
    return 0;
}
```

```
Basics: Visual Studio Code, C++

When I ran the above code it responded with the following in the terminal: "Enter your age: 22 Your age is: 22%"

Does this mean the user would only see 22 or would they see 22%?
```

Comment: The error message is clear: "use of undeclared identifier 'cout'; did you mean 'std::cout'?"

Comment: The code you posted is not the code the compiler is complaining about. `std:cout << "Hello world!";` doesn't appear *anywhere* in  this code. Regardless, I using the xcode-select installation of the full clang command line tools with my vscode, and never ran into this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The #include<iostream> exists, but I get an error: identifier "cout" is undefined. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208547/the-includeiostream-exists-but-i-get-an-error-identifier-cout-is-undefine)

Comment: The issue is the lack of a newline and your shell (likely zsh) telling you as much.

Answer (score 0):

we need to use `#include <iostream>` to use cout that allows us to print output on the screen.

Edit:

Missing double `std::`
However since you've already mentioned `using namespace std` again prefixing `std::` isn't required.

Edit 2:

Nextline getting appended on same line issue —
To fix it we need to add a newline after our `cout` like

```
   ...
    int number;
    cout << "Enter your age: ";
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Your age is: " << number << "\n";
    return 0;
    ...
```

Comment: I did include it. It is on the very top of the first grey box. What else is wrong with it?

Comment: Is the error log inline with the actual code? I am unable to find any Hello world in the code above.

Comment: It looks as if the program itself was buggy by reading my previous code. I restarted the program and it ran. New question, When I ran the above code it responded with the following in the terminal: "Enter your age: 22
Your age is: 22%                                                                                                                     
alexandermorse@Alexanders-MacBook-Air C++ Practice %" Does this mean the user would only see 22 or would they see 22%?

Comment: User would see 22, however since we didn't explicitly add a new line like ```... number<< "\n";``` the console carried the next output on the same line. So just add a new line in the last cout

Comment: Please correct your question & I'll update my answer, mark answer as accepted if you're satisfied.

Comment: Hi @Alex, incase there are no more questions could we close the question?